# Tktable module installation problem. _tkinter.TclError: invalid command name "table"

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tcl, python-module, tktable

This problem has been reported earlier but I couldn't find the exact solution for it. I installed ActiveTCL and downloaded tktable.py by  "`Guilherme Polo <ggpolo@gmail.com>`" to my `site-packages`, also added `Tktable.dll`, `pkgindex.tcl`, and `tktable.tcl` from `ActiveTCL\lib\Tktable2.11` to my `python38-32\tcl` and dlls . I also tried setting the env variable for TCL_LIBRARY and TK_LIBRARY to tcl8.6 and tk8.6 respectively. But I am still getting `invalid command name "table"`.

What is that I am missing? Those who made tktable work on windows 10 and python 3 , how did you do it? I am out of ideas and would be grateful for some tips on it.

Comment: Looks like nothing has done `package require Tktable` on the Tcl side of Tkinter (or something failed when doing that and swallowed the error, which would be more frustrating). All of which doesn't really help you, but might point in the right direction where a solution might be found?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there was problem running the Tktable dlls in python38-32 bit version. It worked in 64 bit version. 
Thanks @Donal Fellows for your input.